# Achieve javascript functionalities in Python sent emails

Tags: python, html, smtp

I need to implement functionality for my python server to send monthly summary with some data. The data needs to be grouped by its relevance, so I figured out to use tables for this as its fitted best for this purpose.

However there will be 4 tables (one of which might have up to 20 rows), and I want to display them as pages of a tab menu so it will be easier to understand and read because displaying 4 tables in a row might look too complicated for some users.

When implementing I found out that you can't use javascript in the html code of the email as its done for security reasons.

I tried including it in a script tag, linking as external file hosted online even opening the javascript script file as file in python itself, it was working for css but not for js.

The question is: besides generating a html page with that report and sending the link to the customer or generating an Excel file, what are other ways I can achieve the goal of sending 4 tables and make the data be easier to read?

Comment: As you learned, you can't be too fancy in HTML emails. A link to the web page is best.